# How can I used the DATE and TIME functions in Excel on data exported from SQL?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I have a table in Excel that takes data from an SQL Database. When I use the DATE and TIME functions on Excel they don't work. I'm using them inside COUNTIFS. I'm also really new to SQL, like two days in, so bear with me here.

When I export the same data table from SSMS results as a CSV file it works perfectly fine, but I need the data to go through Excel for the sake of automation.

Here is a snippet of the sql query:

```
select  CallNumber,
        CallTime,
        CONVERT(date, CallTime) AS DateOfCall,
        CONVERT(time(0), CallTime) AS TimeOfCall
```

Here is the COUNTIFS I'm using:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table2[[#All],[DateOfCall]],">="&DATE($C$2,0,1),Table2[[#All],[DateOfCall]],"<"&DATE($C$2+1,1,1),Table2[[#All],[TimeOfCall]],">="&TIME($D2,0,0),Table2[[#All],[TimeOfCall]],"<"&TIME($D2+1,0,0))
```

The use of that COUNTIFS just gives me 0 as it doesn't seem to recognize the date/time formats.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the dates coming out of the SQL query are in the right format for the formula? You may need to specify a date style, e.g:

```
CONVERT(date, CallTime, 103)
```

The style codes can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I just tried that but no luck. At first I tried 101, but nothing changed neither in the SQL results nor in the excel sheet. I tried a few other with no change. What's interesting is the exported CSV is exactly how I want it with no changes required.

Comment: In that case it may be that they're inadvertently converted to text when imported into the sheet. I'd check to see if changing the format of the columns the data is imported into works first. Failing that you may have to add a column that multiplies the input dates / times by 1 in order to force Excel to recognise them as dates.

Comment: I got it to work with a very similar method. Instead of multiplying by 1 I converted it via the DATEVALUE and TIMEVALUE functions.